# Selenium IDE 3.0.1 - run Selenium IDE script in different browser

Tags: selenium

I have selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1 and drivers for ie and chrome and execute this command perfectly

java -jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=.\IEDriverServer.exe selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar

All ok and up NEW session on ie, but dont execute any test case and generate error show me javascript Alert.

Received command response (!=OK/ERROR):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/displayhelpservlet.css" media="all"/>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/displayhelpservlet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var json = Object.freeze

    ('{"version":"3.0.1","type":"Standalone","consoleLink":"/wd/hub"}');

  </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <div id="help-heading">
    <h1><span id="logo"></span></h1>
    <h2>Selenium <span class="se-type"></span>&nbsp;v.<span class="se-version"></span></h2>
  </div>
  <div id="content-body">
    <p>
      Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page.
    </p>
    <p>
      For more information about Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> please see the
      <a class="se-docs">docs</a> and/or visit the <a class="se-wiki">wiki</a>.
      <span id="console-item">
        Or perhaps you are looking for the Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> <a class="se-console">console</a>.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Happy Testing!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <footer id="help-footer">
      Selenium is made possible through the efforts of our open source community, contributions from
      these <a href="https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/AUTHORS">people</a>, and our
      <a href="http://www.seleniumhq.org/sponsors/">sponsors</a>.
   </footer>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
 Request Data: cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=*webdriver&2=http%3A%2F%2F10.100.52.34%2Ffin700testfw40%2F&3=&4=webdriver.remote.sessionid%3D90a45d47-319d-4d38-ba96-f1391e939193
```

help me please  :=)

Comment: What framework are you using for your test cases?

Comment: i try executing directly selenium ide in diferent browser don't use framework... 
best

Comment: As a sidenote, this is 2017 and testing in Chrome with Selenium pretty much sucks. Is there an alternative yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem while using selenium server v 3.0.1. Then I tried the previous version, 2.53.0, and it's working fine.